# Pandas - Separating Section Number from Text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a column in a pandas data frame with the following format:

```
ColumnA
========
4 Requirements
Requirement blah blah
Requirement blah blah blah
4.1.1 Requirement Subsection
4.1.1.1 Requirement subsection subsection
blah blah blah
...
```

I am trying to separate the numbers from text. In other words, I would like two columns like the following:

```
ColA      ColB
=================================
4         Requirements
          Requirement blah blah
          Requirement blah blah blah
4.1.1     Requirement Subsection
4.1.1.1   Requirement subsection subsection
          blah blah blah
...
```

The section number will always be at the beginning of the record if it exists. How can I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['ColumnA'].str.extract('^(\d+[.\d]*)?\s*(.*)')

# or with named capturing groups
df['ColumnA'].str.extract('^(?P<ColA>\d+[.\d]*)?\s*(?P<ColB>.*)')
```

Output:

```
      ColA                               ColB
0        4                       Requirements
1      NaN              Requirement blah blah
2      NaN         Requirement blah blah blah
3    4.1.1             Requirement Subsection
4  4.1.1.1  Requirement subsection subsection
5      NaN                     blah blah blah
```